# Can't get dropdown date range wanted with jQuery UI DatePicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the [jQuery DatePicker widget](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) with the display [month and year menus](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/dropdown-month-year.html) and according to their [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange) I can modify the year range for the dropdowns.

I am trying to get it so that it shows the current year `plus minus` one year.

My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $( ".date_from" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-nnnn:+nnnn"
    });

    $( ".date_to" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-nnnn:+nnnn"
    });

});
```

However this only outputs the `current year`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is this the actual code you're using?

Comment: Yes, this is the code I am using to bind it to all elements with that class name. Everything works fine other than the date field only showing the current year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nn and nnnn in the field only represent formats, not actual values. Allowing you to:

- Limit absolute years (the nnnn format). So if you have `dateRange: '1900:2000'` The user will be able to select only year between the 1900 and 2000
- Limit using years relative to today (the +/-nn format). So if you have `dateRange: '-13:+07'` the range will be between 2000 and 2020 (since now is 2013)
- Limit using years relative to the *selected* year (the c+/-nn format). So if you have `dateRange: 'c-1:c+1'` and the user has selected 2010, the range will be between 2009 and 2011, but when the user selects 2011, the range will change to 2010-2012

I assume you need to use the `dateRange: '-01:+01'` format so the dates range +/- one year from today.

For more information you can reference [The Datepicker documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange).

Comment: As the documentation says though this will only limit the dropdown, not the actual values that can be selected and minData/maxDate might be a better choice for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use minDate / maxDate with `"-1y"` / `"+1y"` which would be more effective.

Comment: From what I understand that is only for the currently selected year; not the current year.

Comment: Yeah true, but it's not that I really want to restrict the date, it's more just for a better user experience. :) Guess I can use that if I have to :)

Comment: You might as well if you are restricting the dropdown since they won't be able to select greater than +/- 1 year anyway =P